# Use feedburner email subscription without Popup

Tags: email, popup, subscription, feedburner

For my selfhosted Wordpress blog, i wish to add Feedburner email subscription form.

Embed code from feedburner site:
    `<form action="http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify" method="post" target="popupwindow" onsubmit="window.open('http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=[BLOGNAME]', 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=yes,width=550,height=520');return true">`

My issue is, i dont want the popup window to show up. That thing is so 80's stuff.
Instead, is it possible to show the popup contents inline? Using JS or PHP or something?

Check out how div contents change over click here using JS: http://www.willmaster.com/library/web-development/replace-div-content.php

Would be great if something similar could be worked out.

I guess this is easy to do but i have limited knowledge on web designs and php/js/forms.

Thanks in advance.

PS: Please do not suggest plugins. I hate installing plugins unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `target="popupwindow"` to `target="_self"` or `target="_blank"`, it can load in current page or go to a new page.